# What does q stands for in Gq/11 alpha subunit?

Tags: proteins

Sorry for asking, I am not capable to find what does the q stands for in Gq/11 alpha subunits.

Comment: I know the term must have shown up somewhere between [this paper in 1989](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/86/19/7407.full.pdf) and [another in 1995](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC55114/) referencing it.  The latter paper defines Gq as a broader class of proteins, and uses G alpha q for a formerly numbered clone.

Comment: @Mike Serfas Thank you. I am very appreciate that. :)

Comment: @MikeSerfas Since your comment seems to have been useful to the OP, do you want to turn it into an answer?

Comment: @LukasChumchal To make your question more useful for others, can you expand a bit to give context?

Comment: @jakebeal Thank you for noticing my question. I am actually studing for molecular farmacology exam right now and i know that my profesor said that she doesnt know that reason for this abbreviation. So this made me more curious about the it (i am very used to that abbreviation in biology have usually quite important reason behind it). I tried my best to actually find out the answer myself but failed horribly. Thats all what i can said.

Comment: @jakebeal I really can´t think of more specific reason/context for this question. It´s just really about the abbreviation. Nothing else. Nothing more.

Comment: @LukasChumchal This site has a very broad audience and subject matter, so explaining a bit more of what you're talking about would be useful. What is a Gq/11? What is its alpha subunit? Is this a protein? Is it a drug? Does anybody know what a Gq/11 alpha subunit does? Why would anybody care about it?  If you give a couple of sentences like that, it will help people who aren't sitting in class with your professor understand what your question is about.

Comment: @jakebeal you got a poit. However if you have no clue about stuff you mentioned, you are not capable of answer it anyway. So what is even point of adding more information about mechanism/role of Gq/11 in this case?

Comment: @LukasChumchal It will improve the information that you get, because it will demonstrate to people that you actually understand the subject you are asking about, rather than just being a lazy student who is pretending so that you can get somebody else to answer your homework. It will also help other people in the future who may be wondering about the same or similar questions.

Comment: @jakebeal I understood your point from your first comment. However do you thing that this question is really suitable for homework? I understand your life philosophy. However not everybody is in this times lazy individuals, who does not wont to work to archive some goal. Right now i feel like i am getting yelled by you becaus i was curious about this topic. Just you may try to actually find the meaning behind Gq yourself. I faild after reading 5 articles about it.

Comment: @LukasChumchal Apologies, I'm not trying to be rude, but to provide guidance on the typical expectations around question asking at StackExchange. You can read in the help center for more details: https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask If you're not interested in improving your question, that's fine, but be aware that as a result you may receive downvotes and the question may end up closed and deleted.

Comment: @Lukas while I disagree that it should be necessary to explain in your question all the details of how GPCRs work, what would have made the question better would have been to include references to the 5 articles that you have read for instance... It's not so much that we want you to make a 10,000 word essay on everything you know as we want to know where you're coming from and what you've tried so far.  It might not make much difference in this particular case, but for future reference, questions will be better received with such information included.  Thanks! Oh, and welcome aboard!